# encode and decode from html to php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

backup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var key=45;
var value=65;
var rated = {"key" : key , "value" : value};
var rated_encoded = JSON.stringify(rated);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "text.php",
  dataType:"json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
  processData: false,
  data: {
    "rated" : rated_encoded
  },
  //success: function(data) {
    //document.write(data);
  //}
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("text.php");
});
});
</script>
<div id="div1"><h6>Result</h6></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

text.php:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["rated"])){
$rated_json = $_POST["rated"];
$JSONArray  = json_decode($rated_json, true); 
if($JSONArray !== null){ 
    $key = $JSONArray["key"];
    $value = $JSONArray["value"];
}
echo $key;

} 
?>
```

All i want to be able to do is print $key and $value in text.php so that it can be displayed in backup.html. echo $key is not working. In place of that, echo "hello" is also not working. I can only echo something if i type echo "something" outside the isset function. How can i print $key and $value? Thanks!

Comment: Can you see any errors when you debug the xhr request?

Comment: I don't know what that is and how to look at that. Please explain so i can check and get back to you.

Comment: In your browser, pres <kbd>F12</kbd> and open the network tab. Now open your webpage and let us know if you see any errors. :)

Comment: Nopee. No errors are being shown.